# Beginner Android Strings textView: How to store, display and toggle -> Flashcard app

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

I need some help with storing and displaying strings of text in my flashcard app.  The plan is that when a user taps on the textView (FLASHCARD_FRONT) it toggles to the FLASHCARD_BACK, and be able to navigate between different flashcards (front+back):

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8hrF.jpg)

Ideally I would like to keep the strings on an array so in the future users can add new strings (cards) and navigate thru them.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    Button closeButton, addButton, prevButton, nextButton;
    TextView question, answer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        closeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.closebutton);
        addButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.plusbutton);
        prevButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prevbutton);
        nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextbutton);

        question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fcfront_textView);
        answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fcfront_textView); //not linked to anywhere atm




        //adicionado
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello TOAST test!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          }
        });
     }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void onPlusButtonClick(View view) {
    }

    public void onCloseButtonClick(View view) {


        String close_msg = "Thanks for trying !! " ;

        Toast.makeText(this, close_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onNextButtonClick(View view) {
    }

    public void onPrevButtonClick(View view) {
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in a lot of different ways, you could use something like a HashMap, which allows you to store a key with a value of the key (A word could be the key, and the definition the value), you could create an SQLite database so that the cards would be stored on the device and easily reloadable on each start up of the app.

I would recommend looking into an SQLite database as it will allow you to add, delete, even update cards. This information is also stored on the device so it will always be there as long as the app is.

Comment: Thanks HMiller, Im def looking into SQLite but first I am trying to navigate between cards with pre-stored strings. On a more fundamental level 1st: how to make an onClick textView toggle between 2 static strings, then how to manipulate that onClick function with SQLite

Comment: if you let me see your code I could probably give you some pointers

Comment: This would be very helpful, I'll leave work in 5 hours then Im uploading everything on GitHub, would that work?

Comment: I have posted something that should lead you in the right direction, I will unfortunately be unable to respond for another ~12 hours after now, so hopefully that is enough to get you going. From that point you just need to exchange the strings, etc, etc

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I would recommend defining all your button action clicks in your layout file to the same thing, then you can do this:

lets say you make all your action clicks as follows in your layout xml file

```
android:onClick="action_Clicked"
```

You could then access these methods this way

```
public void action_Clicked(View view){

switch(view.getId()){

    case R.id.fcfront_textView:
        exchange()
        break;

    case R.id.button2:

        break;

    case ...and so on..:

       break;
    }
}
```

This removes the need to create the buttons in the ways you have, you can remove all the following

```
button = (Button) findViewById(...);
```

then, back to the action clicked, lets say you want to do something when you click on fcfront_textView

```
    public void action_Clicked(View view){

    switch(view.getId()){

        case R.id.fcfront_textView:
            exchange();
            break;
        }
    }
```

notice that when the fcfront_textView is clicked, we call the method of exchange(), so we need to create that method

```
private void exchange(){
    //TODO exchange strings
    //we can do this by checking what the currently set string is, and 
    //if it is set as string1, set it as string 2, else set as string1
}
```

Comment: Hello there sorry for the delay.. I had some issues implementing this, because the switch case using the View.Id would only work if I had multiple textViews (multiple IDs), in my case I have 1 textView (so far) and I cant compare the strings of View. I made the changes and did a bit of progress, I would really appreciate if you could take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27038321/android-swapping-strings-on-a-single-clickable-textview